# How to use sed in MacOS to insert tags in HTML file?

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I'm running MacOS Ventura 13.4, and I want to use sed to insert the following `meta` tags (in the given order) to an HTML file `index.html` that is located under the directory called `public`.

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'> 
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'> 
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed  -e '/\<head\>/a<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">' \
     -e '/\<head\>/a<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">' \
     -e '/\<head\>/a<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">' > public/index.html
```

However, this throws the following error:

> sed: 1: "/<head>/a<meta http-e ...": command a expects \ followed by text

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using `\<` (and `\>`) because you think `<` is a regexp metachar and are trying to make it literal or because you know it's literal and are trying to make it a metachar (word boundary)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the error message says, MacOS `sed` wants the text to insert to have a backslash.

I'm also guessing you mean `<head>`, not just any `head` with a word boundary on either side (and if that's what you need, the syntax on MacOS for that (and generally on POSIX) is `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` (sic)).

```
sed -e '/<head>/a\
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">\
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">\
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">'
```

You can't nest single quotes, so I switched to double quotes around the attributes. If you genuinely require single quotes, try `'"'"'` (which is ending single quote for the string beginning after `sed -e`, beginning double quote, lone literal single quote, ending double quote, beginning single quote to continue the long string).

You are not revealing where the standard input is supposed to come from; did you mean to run this with `sed -i ''` perhaps? Though then you can't use redirection before the file name.

```
sed -i '' -e '/<head>/a\
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">\
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">\
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">' public/index.html
```

(Notice that this will permanently alter the original file. Don't use `-i` if that's not what you want.)

Technically, there is no requirement for the closing wedge after `<head` to be immediately adjacent to the header name, or even on the same line. If you need complete robustness, `sed` is simply the wrong tool for this (or, well, it's Turing complete, so you *could* implement a proper XML parser if you really wanted to; but really, you don't). On MacOS, maybe look at the `xmllint` tool which is included out of the box (at least with XCode) or a proper XML tool like `xmlstarlet`.